# C string recursive function to find out equality from middle

Tags: c, string, pointers, c-strings

i feel kinda lost, since we started learning about pointers i kinda cant follow and i know its really important subject in C.

anyway!

so i got to make a recursive function, that will get 2 pointers:

1) pointer to index [0].

2) pointer 2 to the middle of the string.

now.. i gotta check if the first part from 0 to middle is equal from middle to end. like..... ADAMADAM.

before i transfer the string i changed entire lower letters to capitals to avoid case sensitivity... so i got something like this.. but its refusing to work.

also using constant is prohibited...

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define SS 81
int CheckString(char *,int *);

int main() {
    char str[SS];
    int length,len,strcheck;
    printf("Please enter a string:\n");
    fgets(str,SS,stdin);

    len=(strlen(str) - 1);  
    if((len>0)&&(str[len]=='\n'))   // replacing '\n' key to '\0'
        str[len]='\0';

    length=len/2;
    strcheck=CheckString(str,&length);
    if (strcheck==FALSE)
       printf("FALSE.\n");
    else
       printf("TRUE.\n");
    return 0;
}

// function
int CheckString(char *str, int *i) {
if (*str != '\0')
    if (*str == str[*i])
        return CheckString(str+1,i++);
    else
        return FALSE;
    return TRUE;
}
```

so i guess i got some problem with the pointers

Comment: Why did you tag this as `C++`?

Comment: Why are you passing a pointer to `int` to `CheckString()`? And `i++` is probably not what you want here.

Comment: hi david, ty for response... thats what i been asked... by 2 pointers.

Comment: Yes, but why a pointer to `int`? Why not another pointer to `char`? And again, `i++` is wrong; this increments the value of the pointer, not the value pointed to.

Comment: @AlexBoyev If you call recursion up to  `if (*str != '\0')`, `str[*i]` will cause out of array access.

Comment: _pointer 2 to the middle of the string._ Is this `&str[length]` , not `&length`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you mean the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int CheckString(const char *s, size_t *i)
{
    return s[*i] == '\0' || *s == s[*i] && CheckString(s + 1, i);
}

int main( void )
{
    char *s = "ADAMADAM";
    size_t i = strlen(s) / 2;

    int result = CheckString(s, &i);
    printf("%s\n", result ? "true" : "false");

    return 0;
}
```

The program output

```
true
```

Note: maybe you should calculate the value for the second argument the following way

```
    size_t i = ( strlen(s) + 1 ) / 2;
```

Think about this.

Comment: ye but using const chars is also prohibited, i should of mention it :/

Comment: @AlexBoyev It will be  a wrong function declaration if to remove the qualifier. That is the function in this case may not be applied to a constant string. However you may remove the qualifier if you want.

Answer (score 0):

The outer condition in the loop inside `CheckString()` should be checking for `*(str + *i) != '\0'`, or equivalently, for `str[*i] != '\0'`. Also, you do not need to increment `*i`, and certainly not `i`, since that is a pointer. The value `*i` is the distance between the characters being checked in the two halves of the string.

The modified function could look like:

```
int CheckString(char *str, int *i) {
    if (str[*i] != '\0') {
        if (*str == str[*i]) {
            return CheckString(str+1,i);
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: it works perfectly, didnt test for limit points... but could you explain how come the 'i' stays the same without promoting it ?

Comment: The value held by `*i` is just the distance from the front of the string to the middle. So, when you add 1 to `str`, `str + *i` points to the next character after the middle, and so on.

Comment: @Alex-- Note that because of the way you calculate the middle of the string, both `ADAMADAM` and `MADAMADAM` return TRUE.

Comment: str + *i ?... where can you see that ?  or i am missing something  ?

Comment: `*(str + *i)` is eqivalent to `str[*i]`. The point is, you increment the `str` pointer with each recursive call. The distance to the character you check in the back half of the string remains constant.

Answer (score 0):

The problem specification says (more or less):

> I've got to make a recursive function that will get 2 pointers:
>
> 1. pointer 1 to index [0].
> 2. pointer 2 to the middle of the string.
>
> I've got to check if the first part from 0 to middle is equal to the second part from middle to end, like: `ADAMADAM`.

As an exercise in recursion, this is fine; as a way of implementing the functionality, recursion is overkill (iteration is fine).

There is confusion (ambiguity) about the interface to the function — the wording of the question seems to suggest two `char *` values, but the code uses a pointer to an integer as the second argument.  That's singularly peculiar.  An integer value could make sense, but a pointer to an integer does not.

We need to define the conditions carefully.  Taking the example string given (`char str1[] = "ADAMADAM";`), the two pointers might be `char *p1 = &str1[0]; char *p2 = &str1[0] + strlen(str1) / 2;` — meaning `p1` points to the first `A` and `p2` to the third `A`.  Consider an alternative string: `char str2[] = "MADAMADAM";`;  The equivalent formula would leave `p1` pointing at the first `M` and `p2` pointing at the second `M`.

Assuming `p1` and `p2` are incremented in lock-step, then:

- The strings are different if, at any point before `*p2` equals `'\0'`, `*p1 != *p2`.
- If `*p2` equals `'\0'`, then the strings are the same.
- By definition, `p1` and `p2` point to the same array, so pointer differences are legitimate.
- Further, `p1` must be less than `p2` to be useful; `p1` equal to `p2` means the strings are identical trivially.
- There is a strong argument that the 'middle of the string' criterion means that either `p2[p2 - p1] == '\0'` or `p2[p2 - p1 + 1] == '\0'` (for even and odd string lengths respectively).  That is, the distance between the two pointers indicates where the end of the string must be.  It means that using `p1 = &str[0]` and `p2 = &str[2]` (on either of the sample strings) should fail because the end of string isn't in the right place.  And if the string was `"AMAMAMAM"`, using `&str[0]` and `&str[2]` should fail because the end of string isn't in the right place; ditto `&str[0]` and `&str[6]`.
- However, this 'strong argument' is also a design decision.  It would be feasible to simply demand that the substring from `p2` to EOS (end of string) is the same as the string from `p1` for the same length.  In that case, using `&str[0]` with either `&str[2]` or `&str[6]` (or, indeed, with the normal `&str[4]`) on `"AMAMAMAM"` would work fine.

Using some of these observations leads to this code.  If you're really under instructions not to use `const`, simply remove the `const` qualifiers where they appear.  The code will work the same.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static bool identical_halfstrings(const char *p1, const char *p2)
{
    assert(p1 <= p2);
    assert(strlen(p1) >= strlen(p2) + (p2 - p1));
    
    if (*p2 == '\0')
        return true;
    if (*p1 != *p2)
        return false;
    return identical_halfstrings(p1+1, p2+1);
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *strings[] =
    {
        "ADAMADAM",
        "MADAMADAM",
        "nonsense",
    };
    enum { NUM_STRINGS = sizeof(strings) / sizeof(strings[0]) };

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STRINGS; i++)
    {
        const char *p1 = strings[i];
        const char *p2 = strings[i] + strlen(strings[i]) / 2;
        printf("[%s] ([%s]) = %s\n", p1, p2,
               identical_halfstrings(p1, p2) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The second assertion ensures that `p1` and `p2` are pointing to the same string — that there isn't a null byte between the locations pointed at by `p1` and `p2`.

Test case output:

```
[ADAMADAM] ([ADAM]) = TRUE
[MADAMADAM] ([MADAM]) = TRUE
[nonsense] ([ense]) = FALSE
```

Just for the record, an iterative version of the same function is:

```
static bool identical_halfstrings(const char *p1, const char *p2)
{
    assert(p1 <= p2);
    assert(strlen(p1) >= strlen(p2) + (p2 - p1));

    while (*p2 != '\0')
    {
        if (*p1++ != *p2++)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

It produces the same output for the sample data.